# Nasty Limit of sum at infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left (\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a\left[\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{i}{n}}-\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{i-1}{n}}\right]}{a\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{i-1}{n}}}\right) $$

How would I even begin to approach this??

Edit:
So the hints helped... I ended up with $\space\ln\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$

Comment: Have you learned L.H. yet?

Comment: If your formula is correct, remove the multiplying $a$ from top and bottom. Then divide the top by the bottom; it simplifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a \left[ \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{i}{n}} - \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{i-1}{n}}\right]}{a\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{i-1}{n}}}\right) \\ =
&\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{ \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{i}{n}} - \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{i-1}{n}}}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{i-1}{n}}}\right) \\= &\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{i}{n}}}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{i-1}{n}}} - 1 \right) \\ =&\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac1n} - 1 \right] \\ =&\lim_{n \to \infty} n\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} - n \\ =&\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^\frac{1}{n} - 1}{\frac{1}{n}} \\ =&\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\cdot \frac{-1}{n^2} \cdot \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{-1}{n^2}} \\= &\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln\left(\frac{b}{a}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \\ =& \space\ln\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Just for fun, look what I wrote in a comment !

Comment: This is quite easily one of the most painful answers I've written.

Comment: I suspected it could long to type and, since I am very lazy, I didn't do it ! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks!! I was hung up on the limit after evaluating the sums but my arithmetic was a bit off. This clarified everything.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left (\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a\left[\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{i}{n}}-\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{i-1}{n}}\right]}{a\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{i-1}{n}}}\right)  = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left (\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} n \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}-n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}} \overset{Hop.}{=} \lim_{n \to \infty}  \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\text{ln}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right) = \text{ln}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right).$$